# Making several "look-alike" images using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have a 112x92 image, *img.jpg*, say. I would like to have several images that look-alike with it. Is it possible to be done using matlab?
What I have tried was as follow:

```
A=imread(img.jpg)
```

It will give 112x92 uint8 matrix

I tried to add `A` with some uint8 matrix `B`. However, I didn't get what I wanted. Could anyone help me please? I am really newbie in image processing

Comment: There are several ways you could do it. Do you want to add noise, or filter the image maybe? Please explain more clearly what you mean by "look-alike". How would you say an image is looks like another?

Comment: @Benoit_11: yes, indeed. I'd like to add noise, change ilumination, or changing pose (like little turned, etc), if possible. How do I do that?

Comment: If you want to change the pose, there is an excellent function called [`jitterImage`](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/images/jitterImage.html) in [Piotr Dollar's toolbox](http://vision.ucsd.edu/~pdollar/toolbox/doc/index.html). Download the entire toolbox, set it up (quite easy) and run `jitterImage.m` to change pose.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure of exactely what you are after, but here are a few things to get you strated:

```
I=imread('peppers.png');
```

Rotation:

```
rotI=imrotate(I, 45, 'crop');
```

[image: image 1]

Added noise:

```
noisyI=imnoise(I, 'salt & pepper', 0.3);
```

[image: image 2]

Directional shear:

```
tform = affine2d([1 0 0; .3 1 0; 0 0 1]);
shearedI = imwarp(I,tform);
```

[image: image 3]

Projective distortion:

```
theta = 1;
tform = projective2d([cosd(theta) -sind(theta) 0.001; sind(theta) cosd(theta) 0.001; 0 0 1]);
projI = imwarp(I,tform);
```

[image: image 4]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is is possible to remove 1 the onion for example? Or some other regions?

Comment: @Jlamprong based on its color?

Comment: @Jlamprong look into color-based image segmentation, there is a whole field about that. I think you would get more useful answers with more specific questions.